# Android Data Binding NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I'm not able to setup my project to use Android Data Binding. This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta2'
        classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4"
    }
}

android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    ...
}
```

When I build, I get this error:

> [data binding plugin]: failed to setup data binding
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;Landroid/databinding/tool/writer/JavaFileWriter;IZ)V

**EDIT**

I have modified `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

But I still get the same error. Also I have this `apt` config:

```
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}
```

Since I'm using AndroidAnnotations.

Comment: remove  classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should now set it up with 1.5.0 and without the explicit data binding import:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

Android Data Binding 1.0 was released as part of the Android gradle plugin.

Comment: I have tried this but get the same error. Look at my edit.

Comment: Hmm... Do you still have the `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'`? If so, you should remove that. You may have a stray `dependencies { classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4' }` in a root build.gradle. If that's not it, perhaps you can post a project that I can look at.

Answer (score 4):

Though George's answer is correct I think it's important to make it clear what should be in each one of the `build.gradle` files.

So, in the project's `build.gradle` file we should have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

And in the app's build.gradle file there should be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// No need to add it as a plugin
// apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'

android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion <latest>
    buildToolsVersion <latest>
    ...
}
```

We don't need to add `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'` in the app's `build.gradle` file because, as George said:

> Android Data Binding 1.0 was released as part of the Android gradle
>   plugin.

Check the [Data Binding Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) for more details.